# Maximum OR Statements in Match RegExpMatchArray

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, gmail

I am using the following code to delete spam messages that have specific words or phrases in them. I am having trouble finding what the limit is for the number of OR statements that I can have. I know I will eventually hit the ceiling. Can someone provide this information?

```
if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/car|truck|van|house|cat|dog|apple|orange|(you won)/gi) !== null) {
  console.log('Msg Delete')
  console.log(i)
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', msg.getId())
  continue;
}
```

Comment: I think Max limit is the string limit in js.

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but as you increase the number of items in the alternation you may find there is a point where it's faster to use a regex to simply match words and then use code to compare those words against a list of words that would have comprised the alternation. Alternatively, you may find it faster to not use a regex at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) there is no mention of limit for `OR` statements, however, you should consider the string limit in Apps Script / JavaScript, since Apps Script is a JS platform I would say the limit is based on the JS documentation, I could not find official documentation for Apps Script but you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description):

> The language specification requires strings to have a maximum length
> of 253 - 1 elements, which is the upper limit for precise integers.
>
> - In V8 (used by Chrome and Node), the maximum length is 229 - 24 (~1GiB). On 32-bit systems, the maximum length is 228 - 16 (~512MiB).
> - In Firefox, the maximum length is 230 - 2 (~2GiB). Before Firefox 65, the maximum length was 228 - 1 (~512MiB).
> - In Safari, the maximum length is 231 - 1 (~4GiB).

Also, it's recommended to follow [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to keep a good performance of your scripts. By making your statement longer, the performance of the script may decrease and you could also encounter other limitations like [script runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

**References:**

- [String length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)
- [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Right now, I only have around 20 key words or phrases. In the event the list of words/phrases continues to grow, I will look into using the suggestions mentioned in the post. Right now, my email is being bombarded by the same junk emails and I want a way to easily see the other emails in my spam folder that might be legitimate emails that are not truly spam.